# error importing installed python packages in nodejs pyshell

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed a package using `pip` on my Ubuntu 18.04 server.

When I go into the terminal and type the following, everything works fine :

```
$ python
>>> import <package-name>
```

I am able to use the package functions etc.

But when I do it through the `const PythonShell = require('python-shell');` utility in `Node.Js`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<package-name>'` (the `import <package-name>` code is the only thing in the python file I am running using the python shell in node.js)

What could explain that difference of treatment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else gets bogged down in those stupid path issues, here is the actual issue and my solution.

The issue is that some python packages were installed through `pip` and others through `apt-get` and `python-shell` does not load the `pip` ones.

For my specific example, I was trying to load a package which, on my machine, is located in

```
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ -> pip install
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ -> pip install
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ -> apt-get install
```

For some reason the `python-shell` can only import library from the `/usr/lib` path.

The solution is to either

1. Copy the library folder from your `site-packages` to the `/usr/lib/` path
2. Insert the following at the top of your code so you can still update the package if need be through `pip`

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path.insert(0, "/the/site-packages/path/you/want")
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the `ModuleNotFoundError` because you don't have the `python-shell` node module installed. You have python installed correctly. Assuming you have node/npm installed correctly as well, you can run the following to install the `python-shell` node module:

- `npm install python-shell`

By doing so, your module will now resolve. Note that `python-shell` package from `pip` is for use within `python`, but it can't be used within a node script. To use inside of a node script, you would want the `python-shell` node module. They're two different things. `pip` packages cannot be used inside of `node`, and `npm` packages cannot be used inside of `python`.

Comment: My question might be unclear. When I run the script `import <package-name>` through the python-shell I get the error. The shell itself works fine insofar as launching the script.

Comment: python-shell is in my package.json etc